# Rigid body physic simulation error?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation, rigidbody

I want to create an animation with a ball that hits a lot of boxes.
The movement of ball must happen in a few fractions of a second > 5 frames:
[image]

here is my blend file v2.8, same bug in blender 2.79 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yI7ClLijo1Ktlw_jCPS6PqY5VyZ-Gd0r

First of all, I made sure that: I checked the normals, increasing the scale of the objects, I applied all transforms for scale, position and rotation
set Origin > origin to geometry, I increasing the Steps per second and Solver Iterations in the Rigid Body World settings (I tried with the maxima 1000 and 100), I set collision shape to Mesh and tried 0.4 or 0 as margins and source to final, I increased the size of all objects

Is possible to create an animation like this in blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For the cylinders, set the Collision to "cylinder", And use my settings under the " Rigid Body Dynamics " For the SPHERE, set the dynamics to "animation"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJfd.jpg)

Under Rigid body Dynamics,
Enable " Deactivation "
Enable "Start deactivation"

Comment: thank you, but doesn't work ...

Comment: Do you see the picture I uploaded?

Comment: This answer, although 'accepted', doesn't seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there is a different approach to it, but one problem is that there is no frame at which the ball is in contact with the other rigid bodies. In frame 22 it is in front of the stack and in frame 23 it is already behind the stack. If you position the ball a bit differently that it has one or two frame inside the stack, it will have an effect.

[image]